# OpenVPN slows down drastically after a certain quota

Tags: networking, debian, openvpn

I've configured an OpenVPN server on my Debian server and I'm facing the following issue. When I stream videos from my server through the VPN, after a while, my connection speed drops near to zero. If I disconnect and reconnect, it works. But the issue comes back a bit later.

I've scoured the Earth looking for an answer, but all the topics I've seen on the Internet are not related.

Here's what my OVPN file typically looks like:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote my_dyndns_address 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
verb 3
key-direction 1
auth-nocache
[certificate stuff]
```

And here's my server configuration

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert MyServer.crt
key MyServer.key
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
crl-verify crl.pem
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. It was not related to my OpenVPN configuration, but to my 4G French carrier Sosh who seems to be detecting this as an unusual traffic and ends up clamping the connection speed, probably to avoid abuse. With Wifi networks, it works fine.